# How to uninstall Biztalk adapter pack

Tags: windows, biztalk

I have installed BAP for `x64`and `x32` in my 2008R2 Windows Server. But, somehow in Assembly folder i could able to see multiple Dlls of `x64`and `x32` versions.
I need to uninstall BAP Completely now.

Comment: Just delete the files u dont need anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are working with BizTalk 2010?
To uninstall the adapter pack 2010 completely, make sure you do the following:

- Uninstall all versions of the adapter pack 2010 (both x86 and x64).
- Uninstall the LOB SDK if necessary (depends on your situation)

If any DLLs still remain in the GAC and you are sure you did the previous correctly, you can go ahead and remove them from the GAC manually, but I would not recommend doing that unless you are sure no other applications are using those assemblies.